IOS shortcut to delete messages based on content
Please help! For many months now I receive spam messages (SMS) almost daily from two sources, each with a clear identifyer. I would need an IOS shortcut for my iPhone that runs - preferably automatically - each time a new message is received, that goes along the lines of ’If message text contains ”XYZ” then delete’ preferably also blocking the sender. I have tried to put this together myself without success, so now I hope someone smarter than me will have pity on me.
Thanks,
Johan
